# C++: Undefined reference to void function

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

**About**

This program should return an age by comparing the current date (month and year entered by user) to the given month and year.

I have attempted to create this program with two functions. 'int age ()' calculates the age, while 'char cont ()' allows the user to continue entering data.

**Problem**

Upon trying to compile, I get the following message:

undefined reference to `age(int, int, int, int, int&, int&, char)'

**Question**

How do I fix this problem?

**Program in question:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void age (int month_now, int year_now, int month_birth, int year_birth, int& age_year, int& age_month, char letter);  


char cont ();

int main ()

{

int month_now;
int year_now;
int month_birth;
int year_birth;
int age_year;
int age_month;
char again;
char y;

cout<<"Enter today's 4-digit year: :"<<endl;
cin>>year_now;

cout<<"Enter today's 2-digit month number: "<<endl;
cin>>month_now;

cout<<"Enter the 4-digit year of your birth: "<<endl;
cin>>year_birth;

cout<<"Enter the 2-digit month number of your birth: "<<endl;
cin>>month_birth;

age(year_now, year_birth, month_now, month_birth, age_year, age_month, again);


return 0;
}


void age (int month_now, int year_now, int month_birth, int year_birth, int& age_year, int& age_month, char letter, char y)
{
do{

if (month_now<month_birth)
 {
    age_year=year_now-year_birth-1;
    age_month=month_now-month_birth+12;

 }
else
 {
    age_year=year_now-year_birth;
    age_month=month_now-month_birth;

 }

char cont ();

}while (letter==y);
}


char cont (string message)
{
    char letter;

    cout<<"Do you wish to find another age? (y/n)"<<endl;
    cin>>letter;

    letter= tolower(letter);

    return letter;
}
```

Comment: The signature of `age` is not the same in the declaration as the definition, you're missing `char y`.

Comment: BTW  the variable `again` is never initialized.

Comment: The `cont` function is also inconsistently prototyped. The reason it doesn't cause a link error is that you never call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *definition* of `age` has an extra `char` parameter compared to the function prototype.

You need to make sure the function name and the parameter types (not the parameter names) match up.

Also, the behaviour on passing the *uninitialised* variable `again` *by value* to a function is *undefined*. Either initialise it in `main`, or pass it by reference and make sure the function initialises it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the call of the `age` function is done according to its declaration at the top of the file. However, the implementation of this function which comes at the bottom has different signature - it has one additional parameter `char y`. Therefore it compiles, but cannot link since there is no implementation of the function corresponded to the declaration.